# OpenGL textured quads and untextured quads

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

How would I go about having both textured quads and untextured quads both being rendered. The issue is if I have textured quads drawn the untextured quads do not show if the textured one is drawn after, and vice versa.

I'm using LWJGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before your textured quads, and `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before your untextured qauds.